# Slice last 2 objects of a column in multidimensional JSON array

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, object, javascript-objects

I may have overlooked a topic with the same question. But i can't seem to figure it out. I would like to remove the last to items in the column. Tried a forEach but it wouldn't work for me, it deletes the complete first column of myArr (for example). Maby instead of delete a Slice?

For example i have this JSON array (myArr):

```
    let myArr = JSON.parse(this.responseText);
    let myColumnYears = Object.keys(myArr);
    let myColumnInhabitants = 
    Object.values(myArr[0]);

    myArr.forEach(function() {
          delete myColumnYears[0];
        });

[
 {
    "1996": "7959017",
    "1997": "7968041",
    "1998": "7976789",
    "1999": "7992324",
},
{
    "1996": "10156637",
    "1997": "10181245",
    "1998": "10203008",
    "1999": "10226419",
},
{
    "1996": "7071850",
    "1997": "7088906",
    "1998": "7110001",
    "1999": "7143991",
}
]
```

And i would like to remove the last 2 objects of each array so the result becomes:

```
[
{
   "1996": "7959017",
   "1997": "7968041",
},
{
   "1996": "10156637",
   "1997": "10181245",

},
{
   "1996": "7071850",
   "1997": "7088906",
}
]
```

I'm missing being a little more specific i guess.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can iterate over array using `.map()`, pick the properties you are interested in and return them as object.

```js
let data = [
  {"1996": "7959017", "1997": "7968041", "1998": "7976789","1999": "7992324"},
  {"1996": "10156637", "1997": "10181245", "1998": "10203008", "1999": "10226419" },
  {"1996": "7071850", "1997": "7088906", "1998": "7110001", "1999": "7143991" }
];

let result = data.map(o => ({"1996": o["1996"], "1997": o["1997"]}));

console.log(result);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```